# Create networks in separate docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, configuration, devops, docker-network

I'm trying to define my networks in separate docker-compose.yml file (`docker-compose.networks.yml`).

Here it is:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

networks:
  pypinfo-rabbitmq:
    name: pypinfo_rabbitmq
    driver: bridge
```

When I try to apply this configuration it shows the following warning:

```
WARNING: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: pypinfo-rabbitmq
```

The main configuration file is:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: pypinfo_rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - rabbitmq_log:/var/log/rabbitmq/
    networks:
      - pypinfo-rabbitmq
volumes:
  rabbitmq_data:
    driver: local
  rabbitmq_log:
    driver: local
networks:
  pypinfo-rabbitmq:
    external:
      name: pypinfo_rabbitmq
```

And when I apply my main configuration file for my services it says:

```
ERROR: Network pypinfo_rabbitmq declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create pypinfo_rabbitmq` and try again.
```

**The question:** Why are my networks defined in `docker-compose.networks.yml` not created? Why should I do to force `docker-compose` to create them?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I can just apply both files at the same time:

```bash
docker-compose -f docker-compose.rabbitmq.yml -f docker-compose.networks.yml up -d
```

It will create the network and containter that has this network in `networks` section in configuration:

```bash
Creating network "pypinfo_rabbitmq" with driver "bridge"
Recreating pypinfo_rabbitmq ... done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create network before running docker compose up

```
docker network create pypinfo-rabbitmq
```

Comment: It should work, of course. The case is that I want to store those networks in docker-compose.yml file (separate file). So that I don't need to recreate them everytime.